# Sitecore - Profile Keys, maximum number?

Tags: personalization, experience-profile

I'm currently working with a client who would like to start using personalisation for their product range.

We've mapped out the number of profiles, profile keys and pattern cards which need to be created however my concern is there's quite a large number required.

We'll start small and test and learn to rollout however I just wanted to check is there a limit on:

1. The number of profiles that can be created?
2. The number of profile keys that can be created under a profile?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

There is not limit on the number of profiles or number of keys in Sitecore. However there may be performance impact if the number of profile cards added to page are more

Comment: Its good that you are starting small and building up.  I would recommend not having more than 8 Profile Keys per Profile.  The values on the radial chart for the Profile and Pattern Cards, becomes difficult to interpret when there are too many Profile Keys.